# Mongoose find documents then limit per variable type, not global

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, mongoose, limit

Can I execute a `.find()` documents but limit the returned documents on a specific `field`, let say that it will only return 5 `groups` (schema) for each `type` (schema field) of group?

I tested `.limit` but it is a global limit rather than a field specific limit.

I know that I can find then postproccess the returned docs but I want a Mongoose specific way to do this, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more of search did the work :D

In resume, it can be uses the `.find().distinct()` method.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315992/does-mongooses-distinct-function-support-regex-in-a-query) is the complete answer: